# Where is the best place to get the "Hot PotatOwned" achievement in HL2: EP2?

Tags: achievements, half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-two

I'm using a PC, so I can't just get the achievement in HL2 or HL2: EP1.

I would like to know, where the best place is to get the achievement.

Comment: I don't understand... HL2 and HL2:EP1 were updated more than one year ago to add achievements in the PC (and Mac) version: http://store.steampowered.com/news/3873/

Comment: You can only get the specific achievement in HL2:EP2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"sadly the only half life 2 to have achievements in the pc version is episode 2 so in order to get this achievement you must pick the **riding shotgun** chapter and play through til you get here, there arent many combine in episode 2"

Chapter riding shotgun after Alyx tells you she recognizes that peak from white forest,it is 2nd big combat in that chapter.

Note:the blonde girl is mod that changes alyx.

Comment: "sadly the only half life 2 to have achievements in the pc version is episode 2" This would be wrong, but [HL2](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/HL2/achievements) and [HL2:Ep1](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/HL2:EP1/achievements) have different achievements.

Comment: Its quote from video,but people keep saying that you might be able to do the ep2 achievement in ep1 on consoles,maybe they are shared or something...